# How to set colorscheme of vimdiff using .vimrc

Tags: colorscheme, vimdiff

I want to set colorscheme during vimdiff at startup. Note this colorscheme would be different than Vim's colorscheme.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an auto command to achieve this:

```
augroup VimDiff
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter,FilterWritePre * if &diff | colorscheme default | endif
augroup END
```

I found `FileWritePre` in the thread [*Diff mode only mappings*](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Diff-mode-only-mappings-tp1146738p1146739.html). This event allows you to enable specific settings after Vim started and when diff mode is set, with `:diffthis` for example.

If you want to check only once (for `vim -d`), `VimEnter` is enough but you should get rid of the auto command altogether (as [Christian](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13394/how-to-set-colorscheme-of-vimdiff-using-vimrc/13395#comment22961_13395) pointed out):

```
if &diff
    " setup for diff mode
else
    " setup for non-diff mode
endif
```

Read [`:h diff`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/diff.txt.html) for more details.

Comment: I think even using `if &diff | colors foobar |endif` in the vimrc might already work.

Comment: Edited with both solutions :)